# What is the intuitive explanation for the CDF of any random variable to follow uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variable

What is the intuitive explanation for the CDF of any random variable to follow uniform distribution?

While i'm clear with the mathematical proof, I'm looking for an intuitive explanation to this.

Comment: The probability that a random variable assumes a value less than the value for which the probability the random variable assumes a value less than that value is $t$, is $t$.

Comment: @LUCIFER Imagine a rectangle since the uniform distribution looks like this. Starting from the bottom left of the rectangle(the origin) , if you move your point more rightwards, the area of the rectangle increases. Since the area is base times height, but the height is fixed, you know that the area increases at the same rate that the distance your point has moved from the origin.

Comment: I should not have use the word rate. But, the area of the rectangle is determined by the distance of your point from the origin. The rate it increases is actually determined by it's height.